Horizontal alignment breaks when using `\label<...>{..}`
I have a tex file
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{cap=true}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Sketch proof of Theorem 1}

\begin{visibleenv}<+->
Consider
\begin{align}
\partial_t \mu_t &= - \partial_{x_i} \{b^i (t, x) \mu_t \} + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{x_i} \partial_{x_j} \{ a^{i, j} (t, x) \mu_t \} . \tag{L-FP} \label<1-2>{prelim:eq2}
\end{align}
\end{visibleenv}

\begin{visibleenv}<+->
We have \eqref{prelim:eq2}.
\end{visibleenv}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

I use \label<...>{..} from this answer to make equation numbering appear in both slides 1 and 2. They are originated from the same frame.
However, there is a problem in alignment:

Replacing \label<...>{..} with \label{..}, the alignment is fine:

Could you elaborate on this issue and how to solve it?

Please make a minimal reproducible example.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have made my code sample a MWE.

It does not look very minimal. Does it matter which footline you use to reproduce the problem? Does it matter what title the frame has? Does it matter what the equation is?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have edited my thread.

Personally I wouldn't use showonlyrefs and all the subsequent problems, but instead only tag the equations you need.
However here a quick hack:
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align}
a &= b\makebox[0pt]{\label<1>{prelim:eq1}}\\
c &= d\makebox[0pt]{\label<1>{prelim:eq2}}
\end{align}
\eqref{prelim:eq1}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Could you elaborate on why there is this problem?

Your solution works perfectly fine. Many thanks.

@Akira You're welcome!
